# when i restart my app, the added medications are no longer available, all the data is gone

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, sqflite

I am creating an app which is supposed to store data using sqflite but everytime restart the app old data is gone, What am i doing wrong?
My main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/models/medication_model.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/providers/medication_provider.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/screens/add_medication_screen.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/screens/medication_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/screens/medication_list_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => MedicationProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MedBuddy',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: {
          '/': (context) => const MedicationScreen(),
          '/addMedication': (context) => const AddMedicationScreen(),
          '/medicationDetails': (context) {
            final medication = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Medication;
            return MedicationDetailsScreen(medication: medication);
          },
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Database helper

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

import '../models/medication_model.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;

  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();


  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _initDatabase();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    final String path = await getDatabasesPath();
    final String dbPath = join(path, 'medications.db');
    final bool exists = await databaseExists(dbPath);
    if (!exists) {
      // If the database doesn't exist, create a new one
      return openDatabase(
        dbPath,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: _createDatabase,
      );
    } else {
      // If the database already exists, open it
      return openDatabase(dbPath);
    }
  }


  Future<void> _createDatabase(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE medications(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT,
        type TEXT,
        dosage TEXT,
        start_date INTEGER,
        end_date INTEGER,
        atTime TEXT,
        date_time INTEGER,
        atInterval INTEGER,
        notes TEXT
      )
    ''');
  }

  Future<int> addMedication(Medication medication) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.insert('medications', medication.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> updateMedication(Medication medication) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.update(
      'medications',
      medication.toMap(),
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [medication.notificationIDs],
    );
  }

  Future<int> deleteMedication(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.delete(
      'medications',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  Future<List<Medication>> getMedications() async {
    final db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> medicationData = await db.query('medications');
    return medicationData.map((data) => Medication.fromMap(data)).toList();
  }
}
```

My provider

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/models/medication_model.dart';
import 'package:medbuddy/utils/database_helper.dart';

class MedicationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Medication> _medications = [];

  List<Medication> get medications => _medications;

  DatabaseHelper database = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  void addMedication(Medication medication) async {
    _medications.add(medication);
    notifyListeners();
    final db = await database.database;
    await db.insert('medications', medication.toMap());
  }

  void updateMedication(Medication medication) async {
    final index = _medications.indexWhere((element) => element.notificationIDs == medication.notificationIDs);
    _medications[index] = medication;
    notifyListeners();
    final db = await database.database;
    await db.update('medications', medication.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [medication.notificationIDs]);
  }

  Future<void> deleteMedication(String id) async {
    _medications.removeWhere((element) => element.notificationIDs == id);
    notifyListeners();
    final db = await database.database;
    await db.delete('medications', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<void> loadMedications() async {
    final db = await database.database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> medicationData = await db.query('medications');
    _medications = medicationData.map((data) => Medication.fromMap(data)).toList();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await loadMedications();
  }
}
```

I am making a medicinal reminder app, I am using sqflite to store data, But everytime i add the data and then restart the app, the previous data is gone. I tried getting existing database and only creating a new one if one doesnt exist, but it creates a new one every time,

Comment: Just follow this tutorial from flutter - 'https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite'
Maybe you missed something in your code.

Comment: tried this, still upon restart, the data is gone.

Comment: Does await databaseExists(dbPath) returns true?

Comment: yes it returns true

Comment: There was an issue with data type compatibility i fixed those, and there are no further warnings still I cant fix the issue, What else might be the problem?